# Show warning for unused autowired field in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, annotations, autowired

IntelliJ does not show "Field is never used" warning if it have `@Autowired` annotation. How to make it show warning?

Comment: You can't. `@Autowired` on a field means that Spring will set/init that field at some time. There is nothing to warn about :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring-Facet in (File->Project Structure-> facets) to enable Warnings.

Comment: I don't see any "enable warnings" checkbox there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tick the inspection `Unused declaration` (inside `Java/Declaration redundancy` category).

> This inspection reports classes, methods or fields in the specified
>   inspection scope that are not used or not reachable from entry points.

You can find this in Settings -> Editor -> Inspections.

Comment: It is ticked. IntellJ shows warning for unused  fields, unless the field is autowired. I want to extend the use of this warning to autowired fields as well. (However I don't even understand why warning is turned off for autowired fields in the first place.)

Comment: That's strange. When I untick it, the warning message disappears on my unused `@Autowired` field. Is your `Highlighting level`set on `Inspections` ?

Comment: What do you mean, `Highlighting level` ? Where can I find it? If you mean visibility - it's all public.

Comment: Right click on the bar on the right (showing problems, on the scroll bar) -> Customize highlight level -> Inspections.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Settings | Editor | Inspections | Java -> Unused declaration -> Entry points -> Annotations...